# Gas apple syntax error again

Tags: macos, assembly, gnu-assembler, keccak

On this instruction :

`jmp     *KeccakP1600_Permute_NroundsTable-8(rT1)`

Clang said :

error: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode

where

KeccakP1600_Permute_NroundsTable:

```
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds1
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds2
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds3
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds4
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds5
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds6
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds7
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds8
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds9
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds10
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds11
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds12
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds13
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds14
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds15
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds16
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds17
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds18
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds19
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds20
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds21
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds22
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds23
.quad   KeccakP1600_Permute_Nrounds24
```

and

`#define rT1  %rax`

How can i fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: That's not a syntax error. You fix it by using position independent code, such as: `lea KeccakP1600_Permute_NroundsTable(%rip), %rxx; jmp *-8(%rxx, %rax)`. Use an available register for `rxx`.

Comment: Yes.it works, (TestCase ok) Thank you very much.